# Accessing Azure ADLS gen2 with Pyspark on Databricks

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm trying to learn Spark, Databricks & Azure.

I'm trying to access GEN2 from Databricks using Pyspark.
I can't find a proper way, I believe it's super simple but I failed.

Currently each time I receive the following:

```
Unable to access container {name} in account {name} using anonymous
credentials, and no credentials found for them in the configuration.
```

I have already running GEN2 + I have a SAS_URI to access.

What I was trying so far:
(based on this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/azure-datalake-gen2-sas-access):

```
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.account.auth.type.{STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.dfs.core.windows.net", {SAS_URI})
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.sas.token.provider.type.{STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.dfs.core.windows.net", {SAS_URI})
```

Then to reach out to data:

```
sd_xxx = spark.read.parquet(f"wasbs://{CONTAINER_NAME}@{STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.dfs.core.windows.net/{proper_path_to_files/}")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your configuration is incorrect. The first parameter should be set to just `SAS` value, while second - to name of Scala/Java class that will return the SAS token - you can't use just URI with SAS information in it, you need to implement some custom code.

If you want to use `wasbs` that the protocol for accessing Azure Blog Storage, and although it could be used for accessing ADLS Gen2 (not recommended although), but you need to use `blob.core.windows.net` instead of `dfs.core.windows.net`, and also set [correct spark property for Azure Blob access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage#access-azure-blob-storage-using-the-dataframe-api).

Answer (score 3):

The more common procedure to follow is here: [Access Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 using OAuth 2.0 with an Azure service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/azure-datalake-gen2-sp-access)